# Get Button ID on formview

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a problem about formview,i want to get Button ID on formview, button is inside on fvData.
this is a code on vb

```
    Dim oButton As Button = fvData.FindControl("btnRevisi")

    lblError.Visible = False
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        fvData.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)
        fvData.Caption = "Edit Data"

        oButton.Visible = False
    End If
```

this code on HTML

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvData" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsForm"
    DefaultMode="Edit" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="FooterStyle">
                    <uc1:BtnUpdate ID="BtnUpdate1" runat="server" />
                    <uc2:BtnDelete ID="BtnDelete1" runat="server" />
                    <uc3:BtnCancel ID="BtnCancel1" runat="server" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnRevisi" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Style="font-size: 8pt; cursor: pointer; background-position: left; background-image: url(../images/Save.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: right;" Text="Revisi" ToolTip="Save" ValidationGroup="Pricing" Width="55px" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

and when executed the result is
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

how to resolve this?and get the Button id

thanks
best Regards

Comment: please include all code and html markup for us to understand.

Comment: ok, i already update my question, thanks

Comment: which method are you executing??

Comment: humm so i have one command on gridview , when command on gridview = select , i want set **btnRevisi** Visible is false

Comment: method executing when i want to edit command on gridview

Comment: you keep saying gridview.

Comment: The code you posted does not explain the NullReference. What line is the error? In which method is the vb code? When is it executed?

Comment: in essence I just want to grab the id property from the **btnRevisi**, because the location of the **btnRevisi** is in the formview, so the id of the **btnRevisi** can not be called. and display error after the run is **btnRevisi** it is nothing **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: I have declare by using **DirectCast**, the result is the same still (**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**).  like this the code **Dim oButton As Button = fvData.FindControl("btnRevisi")**

Comment: **oButton.Visible = False** in this section its an error

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you are getting the error lies on the returned value. Find control returns the type control. Try casting the return value of findControl to button.

Regards,

Maheshvara